# Add object properties to html element

Tags: javascript

Can I add a custom property to an `HTMLElement` on the dom, and be sure that the browser won't remove it behind my back until the element is garbage collected? I'm currently doing the following:

```js
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.__my_custom_property = my_obj;
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

I want to ensure that `my_obj` lives for at least as long as `el`, and that it will also be garbage collected some time after `el` is.

---

If relevant, in my actual use case I'm using rust wasm, and want to attach an object to the node that will update it's properties (such as inner text, children, attributes, etc.) via a weak reference (to ensure the node can still be dropped without circular references).

I don't want to manage the lifetime of that object by myself, because it only needs to live for as long as the element does.

Comment: the code will work fine as it is

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add a custom property to an HTMLElement on the DOM, and be sure that the browser won't remove it behind my back

Most likely, yes, but can it be guaranteed? No.

*However* you can use [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead. The only caveat here is that it can only hold string values, so you would need to parse the object to/from JSON as you store/retrieve it.

```js
const myObj = { foo: 'bar' }

const el = document.createElement("div");
el.dataset.myCustomProperty = JSON.stringify(myObj);
document.body.appendChild(el);

// For testing this demo
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(el.dataset.myCustomProperty))
});
```

```html
<button>Get prop</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for my specific use case, I'm not sure if storing just a string isn't enough, because my object uses `FinalizationRegistry` to drop itself. Although if I could register a `FinalizationRegistry` on the string in the dataset, it might be doable.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues  If the element can be garbage collected (it's not in the DOM and can no longer be reached in code) then memory used to store its data attributes will be collected in the process, no differently to values for other common attributes such as `src`, `href` or `id`. Simply using a callback from [FinslizationRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) for cleanup would not stop attribute values of the element being collected along with the element.